# Angular: Proper way to inform nested property change between different components

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an application that shows and manipulates users' information in a table with many columns. The user model has quite a few deep nested properties, each table column represent a property. To better explain, I created this simplified app at [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/issue-sample?). The real application has more columns and is relatively organised into more layers/components.

Basically, each column is a component that has an @Input `person`. While `Location` property value is changed by clicking itself, another component `LOS` needs to be aware of it and change its text colour, if location becomes 'J'.

Normally, this isn't working as the `person` reference of each @Input is not changed, so the change detection is not firing.

Please ignore the pipe used as it's just a way to show one component has to react if a property is changed in another component. I can mark it as `impure` but it seems not a good way as it will run too many times unnecessarily.

Also, I know I can make it work by using getter or a function to read the property in another component template, I have included the code as comment in stackblitz app. But it can unnecessarily run many times as well.

**Question**

I wonder if there is another better, cleaner and intuitive way to notify nested property changes between components. It could be a better way of organising the object and its property, passing them to different components, or other techniques that don't bring performance overheads.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you had  chance to try my solution below?

Answer (score 0):

**Component Structure**

You need a a `RowComponent` to segregate each row and its data and coloring of the LOS column (which may differ between rows).

After adding this component, I would not use `LocationComponent` or `LengthofstayComponent` as there is not much to them and your code will become cluttered with passing values between them.

**Implementing the color changing**

I recommend using a `BehaviorSubject`, a corresponding `Observable` and the `async` pipe. Every time the `async` pipe, emits, a change detection cycle will be intiated.

In `RowComponent` add:

```
  showColorSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  showColor$ = this.showColorSubject.asObservable();
```

If we call `next` on the `Subject` in `changeLocation`:

```
this.showColorSubject.next(this.person.location.code === "J");
```

then `showColor$` will emit `true/false` accordingly in the `RowComponent` template where we use the `async` pipe to selectively enable the `color` class:

```
[class.color]="showColor$ | async"
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-color-row-cell?file=src%2Fapp%2Frow%2Frow.component.html
(Formatting is messed up but I'll leave that to you)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The real application already has the RowComponent in which each column is also component, and they all have more complicated functionalities, not as simple as the simplified stackblitz app.

I think your suggestion of using Subject with its observable makes sense in a simpler situation like the stackblitz app, but when things become complex, do you have idea how this approach be utilised?

Comment: 'When things become more complex' - do you mean if say `LocationComponent/LengthOfStayComponent` were present? or some other type of complexity?